# ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false) does not work between two inputs from stdin

Tags: c++, iostream, cin, stdio

I am wondering why does the following code not work as expected:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int n;
    string s;
    //scanf("%d",&n);
    cin >> n;
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    cin >> s;
    cout << n << " " << s;
    return 0;
}
```

Input:

```
10 
abcd
```

Output: `10`

The string is not getting printed! The result is same if I use `scanf` to input the integer. However, the code does work as expected if the line `ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);` is placed before the first `cin` (or before the `scanf`) instead.

I would highly appreciate any help to clarify this behaviour.

**Edit:**
The inputs are contained in a file `inp.txt` and I am using `<` (re-direction operator) to read from the file and `>` to output the result to `out.txt`, like:
`a.out < inp.txt > out.txt`

The code gives expected output if the inputs are given directly from console. Sorry for any misunderstanding or confusion.

Comment: This [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/sync_with_stdio) states that `sync_with_stdio()` must be the first call to the `io` system. - *"It is implementation-defined if this function has any effect if called after some I/O occurred on the standard stream."*

Comment: Add  << endl might not be flushing the output. (Not sure how it works in c++ in c when the program finishes stdout gets flushed)

Comment: @Mr. Branch: Where should I add `<< endl`? Also, how would it be helpful if `stdout` gets flushed? (I think the problem here is with `stdin`, not `stdout`.).

Comment: I ran the program on my pc and had no problem the cin>>n takes the whole line did you try 10(enter) then the string? also the <<endl after <<s.

Comment: @Mr.Branch: The program ran perfectly on your pc! That's strange! So, this indeed depends on the implementation details. By the way, whether the inputs are separated by space or newline is not making any difference on my machine. `<< endl` after `<< s` does no good as well.

Comment: I included #include <string> but nothing else

Comment: @Mr.Branch: Sorry, my question was incomplete. I actually used re-direction operator `<` to read input from a file. Giving the inputs (separated by newline) directly in console seems to be working! I am editing the question.

Answer (score 1):

Calling [`sync_with_stdio`](http://eel.is/c++draft/ios.members.static#2) *after* I/O has been performed leads to implementation-defined behavior (which is stronger wording than cppreference's "has any effect"):

> *Effects:* If any input or output operation has occurred using the standard streams prior to the call, the effect is
>   implementation-defined. Otherwise, called with a false argument, it
>   allows the standard streams to operate independently of the standard C
>   streams.

In libc++, nothing happens because all it does is toggle a flag. In libstdc++, it actually performs [logic](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/4d0a8bacb5d3f49d5b168c0f6d05af60a5cea70a/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/src/c%2B%2B98/ios_init.cc#L165) to switch the streams. Any further attempt to use the streams results in failure:

```
cin >> s;
cin.clear();
cin >> s;
std::cout << n << " " << s;
```

Either way, [the libstdc++ manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/io_and_c.html) states you need to call the function *before* performing I/O. So what you actually have is undefined behavior now.

Comment: My code is not giving expected output when combined with file read with `<` operator, for inputs given directly in the console, it is working fine.

Comment: @SnehasishKarmakar when you're using the console, there is no buffer to lose your input string in