# Why does my cpp program hang up after first line?

Tags: c++

I have this code in cpp that I'm writing for a competitive coding problem.
This code seems to just stop working after the first line. Even if I remove the first line, the code hangs up at the second one. My CPU hums as if I have run into an infinite loop. Neither of the lines can initiate an infinite loop.

See here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9RipC.jpg

Look at the line numbers being printed.

I then removed the line that I figured might be causing trouble. But then the code seems to hang up at the line right after.

See this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qx1Bp.jpg

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>

    #define line cout<<__LINE__<<"\n"; //this prints the line number in code

using namespace std;

int main() {
line  //This prints

ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false); cin.tie(NULL); 

line //This doesn't print at first

freopen("input.txt", "r", stdin); freopen("output.txt", "w", stdout);

line //This doesn't print in both attempts.
...
}
```

This has never happened before. What I don't understand is, even if I might have made some mistake elsewhere, I never touch these two lines. This is my template for competitive coding. Shouldn't these two lines be independent of the rest of the code?

Comment: [`std::flush`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/flush)?

Comment: What is `...`? `ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false); cin.tie(NULL);`  achieves precisely that output might not be flushed when an input is requested. So printing is not how you can see where the program evaluation is because the program might be doing `...` before showing anything.  Please post [mcve].

Comment: "This is my template for competitive coding." Throw it away. There are only two lines in this sample that I would accept in code review: `int main() {` and `}`

Comment: _Toggles on or off synchronization of all the iostream standard streams with their corresponding standard C streams if it is called before the program performs its first input or output operation.

If called once an input or output operation has occurred, its effects are implementation-defined._

Comment: Odd things can happen if you use arcane magical incantations without understanding what they do. (If your program is too slow without the "unsyncing", the problem is with your algorithm, not the I/O. There is nothing competitive about shaving microseconds off an inferior algorithm.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ios\_base::sync\_with\_stdio(false) does not work between two inputs from stdin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37468606/ios-basesync-with-stdiofalse-does-not-work-between-two-inputs-from-stdin)

Answer (score 0):

You are disconnecting `std::cout` from `stdout` immediatly after writing to it. [cppreference has this to say:](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/sync_with_stdio)

> If this function is called after I/O has occurred on the standard stream, the behavior is implementation-defined: implementations range from no effect to destroying the read buffer.

Comment: Fine. But even after commenting out that line, the problem persists.

Comment: You are likely doing something else with (un|implementation-)defined behaviour in the code not shown. If it is undefined behaviour, it can [travel through time](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140627-00/?p=633)